# Using frida and java script to hook protected APK encountered attach( ) error

Tags: android, class, apk, hook, frida

I used the following java script to learn hooking in frida (windows 7).

```
Java.perform(function () { 
            console.log("prepare hook...");
            var application = Java.use("android.app.Application");
            console.log("get application...");
            application.attach.overload("android.app.Context").implementation = function(Context){
                console.log("get context...");
                var classloader = Context.getClassLoader();
                Java.classFactory.loader = classloader;
                console.log("get classloader");
            }
        });
```

What I wanted to do in this exercise is to get the class loader of a protected APK.  In frida -R -f com.xxxx.xxx -l myjs1.js, attach( ) argument type error popped up:

[image]
What's wrong with my javascript and how to fix it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to hook a non-existing method.

What you try to hook:

```
android.app.Application.attach(android.app.Context)
```

The only `attach` method in this class has the signature

```
android.app.Application.attach(android.content.Context)
```

See source code: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Application.java#L350

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the line: application.attach.overload("android.content.Context"). Now I can get the class loader, but the app stops when the last log  console.log("get classloader") completes executing. Any idea why?

Comment: I added this line as the 1st in the function: var result=this.attach(Context), and the app stops crashing now, could you explain how it works?

Comment: Your code totally replaces the `attach(..)` implementation with the JavaScript code. Hence if you don't call the original function in the JavaScript part the function does not what it is supposed to do which can result in crashes or just a wrong behavior of the hooked app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get access with Context, here is alternative on make it works

```
Java.perform(function () { 
    var context = Java.use('android.app.ActivityThread').currentApplication().getApplicationContext();

    console.log("get context...");
    var classloader = context.getClassLoader();
    Java.classFactory.loader = classloader;
    console.log("get classloader");

});
```

Just remove the application implementation.